# Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP) support in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I've got a device that connects to a computer using Bluetooth's SPP (Serial Port Profile) which is widely supported by almost everything however is now considered legacy.

I'm struggling to get my device to work in Yosemite and it doesn't seem to support it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to pair a bluetooth serial port via the preferences panel:

```
Apple Menu > System Preferences... > Bluetooth
```

My adapter was discoverable, failed auto-pairing, but I was able to pair with the pin code provided in the online documentation. The system automatically created a serial port:

```
alf@my-mac:~ ls -l /dev/tty.*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   6 Aug 12 15:09 /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Screen will open this port, but I don't have the correct baud rate just yet:

```
screen /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Comment: I dont think this works any more with MacOS Sierra 10.12